# Android getContentLength always return -1 when downloading apk file

Tags: android, urlconnection

I'm using the following code for downloading file in my Android project:

```
URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
URLConnection conection= url.openConnection();
conection.setDoOutput(true);
conection.connect();
int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
```

If **fileUrl** is apk, **lenghtOfFile** always return -1.
But if it is image, video type,... lenghtOfFile return is exactly.

Why ?

*I'm using eclipse, Android SDK revision 23.*

Comment: it is probably an issue backend side

Comment: have you verified that the file actually exists, and that the server is actually returning a content length for it?

Comment: the file length should be handled by server. your server doesn't provide that.

Comment: Thanks for all.
Resloved by @Markus Kauppinen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The content length is not always available because by default Android request a GZIP compressed response. Source: [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Quoting the link:

> By default, this implementation of `HttpURLConnection` requests that
>   servers use gzip compression and it automatically decompresses the
>   data for callers of `getInputStream()`. The `Content-Encoding` and
>   `Content-Length` response headers are cleared in this case. Gzip
>   compression can be disabled by setting the acceptable encodings in the
>   request header:
>
> `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");`
>
> Setting the `Accept-Encoding` request header explicitly disables
>   automatic decompression and leaves the response headers intact;
>   callers must handle decompression as needed, according to the
>   `Content-Encoding` header of the response.
>
> `getContentLength()` returns the number of bytes transmitted and cannot
>   be used to predict how many bytes can be read from `getInputStream()`
>   for compressed streams. Instead, read that stream until it is
>   exhausted, i.e. when `read()` returns `-1`.

Whether or not the response then actually is compressed depends on the server of course.

Comment: Great. Work like a charm. 
Thanks you very much <3