# returning file size = -1 from server in android

Tags: android, mysql

I am making an android app in which i am fetching images from server which are stored in mysql database.so i needed the file size before downloading and i am using this code

```
       FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

         InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();  
     int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
```

but always i am getting totalsize = `-1`1.I dont know why this is happening.plz help me to resolve this issue

Comment: One related answer to an older question is here: [Android getContentLength always return -1 when downloading apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988325/android-getcontentlength-always-return-1-when-downloading-apk-file/32990226#32990226) and [more related answer can be found on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+getcontentlength+-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the server is not setting `Content-Length` in the response header.

Comment: so can i do this like setting Content-Length in the response header.

Comment: Yes you can do that mate!

Comment: and how can i do this

Comment: Depends on language you have on back-end. You should make another question about that and accept this answer mate.

Comment: i am using php on back-end.can u provide me with this code plz

Comment: header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125509/discussion-between-nicky-manali-and-carnal).

Answer (score 0):

Your web server does not set the appropriate `Content-Length` header.

[From the docs for URLConnection.getContentLength()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength()):

> the content length of the resource that this connection's URL references, -1 if the content length is not known, or if the content length is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

However, even if `getContentLength` *would* return a positive integer to show you how long the content is, [that may be entirely off](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> `getContentLength()` returns the number of bytes transmitted and cannot be used to predict how many bytes can be read from `getInputStream()` for compressed streams. Instead, read that stream until it is exhausted, i.e. when `read()` returns -1.

If you really need to know the file-size, it would be best to define your own header field and use that value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the size is greater than an int can be. It is better to use getContentLengthLong(). This [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength()) may help you.